# Can't scroll HTML page down to see full content

Tags: html, css

Below are the pictures of the css(2 pics) and html

[css top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAL7C.png)  [css down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLMfS.png) [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im9yk.png)

Comment: edit your post and add the css and html, not a picture

Comment: Please see [ask] and post a [mcve], not pictures of code

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set `overflow: scroll` on html element
Also stop putting new lines between html elements